# Div layout issues using CSS

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm trying to layout two Html Tables side by side on my page. when I click on a Portfolio ID on the left side, my trade contribution records show up on the right side.

I use separate divs which allows me to create a header table that locks column headers, and below it create another scrollable table with the data.

Please see sample : http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/6zWdP/1/

**Details**:

One main div for the page - 
Four divs within the page:

**1)** two divs that float left
    **1a)** first div is a table with `<caption>` and `<thead>` and `<th>` headers only
    **2a)** second div is scrollable and contains the full table cell contents, no headers

**2)** two divs that float right
    **1a)** same as above
    **2a)** same as above

As you'll see, my Portfolio Definitions div and table on the LEFT look nice and neat.

However, the Trade Contrib div and table to the right are slightly skewed.

FYI - without this technique of using a separate div for the table col headers, my two table looks great side by side. However they do NOT have the appearance of locked header columns. ex/ http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/bsApv/3/

I will continue experimenting, but some direction and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle had way too much data for my browser to like it, so here's a simple demo. I would probably do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Z47Z9/ Note, `display: inline-block` is not supported by at least IE7 and lower, possibly IE8 too (can't remember).

Comment: I'd also investigate the Twitter Bootstrap [grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), make your life a little easier (and nicer to look at).

Comment: Note, only IE7 and lower do not support `display: inline-block`. If you do not need to support those browser versions, then use `display: inline-block` for this, and *not* a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your div combos in wrapper divs and float those.

```
<div id=left>
    <div id=leftheaders />
    <div id=leftbody />
</div>
```

Comment: One of these days, all *relevant* browsers (IE, I'm looking at you) will support `display: inline-block` and `float` will go back to being for inline purposes.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - thanks for the idea. It worked in the sense that my two divs are now nicely lined up side by side.

Comment: Now I'm having a weird issue with my header on the RIGHT side...the Date column way off to the right - http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/6zWdP/

Comment: table {
            width: 660px;
            border-collapse: collapse;                        
        }  Your table is set too wide for the header.

Comment: thx again Frankie; indeed it was a table width issue. I would like to now fix my <td> positions to always align below my columns; seems that depending on the xml data I pull, the and dynamic width of my cell contents, it skews the width of the <td> elements.